# Construct an increasing function.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, special-functions

When solving a problem, I came to a need of having a function $f$ satisfying the following properties:

(a) $f:\left(1,\infty\right)\rightarrow\left(0,\infty\right)$ is a $C^{2}$ function,

(b) $f'>0$ on $\left(1,\infty\right)$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=\infty$,

(c) $\dfrac{\left(f'(x)\right)^{2}-f''(x)}{f'(x)}\leq\dfrac{1}{x}$
on $\left(1,\infty\right).$

Anyone has an idea to show one? Thank you.

Note that: if $f(x) = \ln(x)$ then $\dfrac{\left(f'(x)\right)^{2}-f''(x)}{f'(x)} = \dfrac{2}{x}$, which is not satisfied but almost!

Comment: $f(x)=\ln x$ also fails the first requirement because $ln(1+\epsilon) \approx \epsilon \lt 1$ for $\epsilon $ small

Comment: Thanks Ross, I only need $f$ is positive.

Comment: @RossMillikan : I note that conditions (b) and (c) are indifferent to vertical translations.

Answer (score 2):

Potentially useful:  Note that since $$  \frac{\left( f'(x) \right)^2 - f''(x)}{f'(x)} = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left( f(x) - \ln f'(x) \right)  \text{,}  $$
we may instead consider 
$$  f(x) - \ln f'(x) \leq \ln x + C  \text{,}  $$
for some constant $C$.  So
$$  f(x) \leq \ln( x f'(x) ) + C  \text{.}  $$

(I'd keep at this, but I have a new rule about not trying to post correct math after midnight.)

Comment: I can post incorrect math any time.

Comment: @martycohen : I'm just trying to upper bound my wrongness, based on Bayesian estimates versus wall time.